# Trouble coding a hyperbolic SOCP constraint in MATLAB, using Yalmip

Tags: matlab, optimization, gurobi

Let's assume we have sdpvar vectors p, q, v2 and y, of 1 column and n rows. r is a vector of constants, of 1 column and n rows.
I want to code the constraint `r(i)* (p(i)^2 + q(i)^2) <=  v2(i) * y(i)`. This is a hyperbolic constraint which has a SOCP form, recognizable by commercial solvers.

My problem is that my optimization program returns `NaN` for all my variables, meaning that nothing was optimized.

Here are some of the ways I tried to code the constraint:

1)

> cone is used to define the constraints norm(x) < y without invoking
>   the overhead of using the norm operator.

```
for i=1:length(r)
    Constraints = [Constraints; cone(sqrt(r(i)*[p(i), q(i)],sqrt(v2(i)*y(i)))];
end
```

2)
[how to rewrite w'w <= xy using norm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v86IF.png)

```
for i=1:length(r)
Constraints = [Constraints; norm([2*sqrt(r(i))*[p(i);q(i)], (sqrt(v2(i))-sqrt(y(i)))]) <= (sqrt(v2(i)) + sqrt(y(i)))];
end
```

3)

```
for i=1:length(r)
Constraints = [Constraints; norm([2*sqrt(r(i)*(p(i)^2 + q(i)^2)); (sqrt(v2(i))-sqrt(y(i)))]) <= (sqrt(v2(i)) + sqrt(y(i)))];
end
```

I would appreciate any help as I am stuck on this for a while now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already answered on the Gurobi google groups forum

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/gurobi/oEC_MbvAidM

Comment: Oh I forgot to mention that r isn't a decision variable. All the rest are.

p.s: I posted here because I thought that more people would see it. Didn't mean to offend you

Comment: Then the question has already been answered on the Gurobi forum.